# R ggplot line is creating vertical lines even though the data is grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I am trying to add a line from a different data set to my current graph. The new data consists of the number of employees working at a given day and time (there are 4 weeks). I summarized that data so that for each day of the week and each time I have the avg number of employees working. However, when I lay the line on my graph it appears with vertical lines. It seems as if its plotting each of the 4 points that are summarized even though when I look at the summarized table there is only 1 point for each Day & Time. Any thoughts what the problem could be?

This is the data that summarizes the # of employees

```
coldcounter <- schedules %>% 
  group_by(`Day of Week`, Time) %>% 
  summarize(emp = sum(`# of Employees`)/4)
```

Which leads to this sample output...note how each time has 1 observation

```
  Day of Week     Time  emp
1           SUN  6:30 AM 1.00
2           SUN  7:00 AM 2.00
3           SUN  7:30 AM 2.00
4           SUN  8:00 AM 2.00
5           SUN  8:30 AM 2.75
6           SUN  9:00 AM 2.00
7           SUN  9:30 AM 2.00
8           SUN 10:00 AM 2.00
9           SUN 10:30 AM 2.00
10          SUN 11:00 AM 2.00
```

Here is the code for the graph (ignore all the aesthetic functions).. the code for the additional line is at the very end

```
kitchen %>%
  group_by(Day, Time) %>% summarise("Sales" = sum(Sales)) %>%
  mutate(percent = Sales/sum(Sales)*100) %>% 
  ggplot()+  geom_bar(aes(x=Time,y=percent,fill=ifelse(percent<1,"Red","Blue")),stat="identity")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90))+
  facet_wrap(~Day)+
  ggtitle("Cold Counter Sales Overview - 11PM Close")+
  ylab("% of Daily Sales")+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkslategray3","red"))+
  labs(fill="Less than or \nGreater than 1%")+
  
  geom_line(data=coldcounter, aes(x=Time,y=emp,group=1))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("6:30 AM","7:00 AM","7:30 AM","8:00 AM","8:30 AM","9:00 AM","9:30 AM","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:00 AM","11:30 AM","12:00 PM","12:30 PM","1:00 PM","1:30 PM","2:00 PM","2:30 PM","3:00 PM","3:30 PM","4:00 PM","4:30 PM","5:00 PM","5:30 PM","6:00 PM","6:30 PM","7:00 PM","7:30 PM","8:00 PM","8:30 PM","9:00 PM","9:30 PM","10:00 PM","10:30 PM","11:00 PM"))
```

Here is what the graph outputs
[image: Graph output]

I am not sure why those vertical lines are appearing

Comment: The most likely reason is that you have multiple obs for some time points And if two obs. share the same x value they will be connected by a vertical line. And after a look at your code I would guess that the reason is that facet by `Day` but the column in `coldcounter` is named `"Day of Week"`. Hence the data for weekdays is replicated in each facet and you end up with multiple values per `Time`. Check your chart. The black line is the same in each facet. And the fix would be to rename `"Day of Week"` as "Day".

Comment: This was the problem - thank you so much!!